# Free open source Widgets for ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, widget

is there any free open source Widgets (iGoogle-like widgets) framework for ASP.NET that I can build my own widgets with and can be used for commercial use (sites developed with it can be sold).

I checked dropthings and Kalitte but they require a licence.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

BlogEngine.NET includes a widgets implementation supporting multiple zones but not drag&drop support. You might check it out.